# Delete from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to delete a specific attribute from each and every table in the database. For an example: I want to delete `CustomerID` (column name) with a value of '2' from each and every table in the database

I am trying to delete records where there is a customer field and it has a value of 2 but I get an error that says there is incorrect syntax near keyword delete

```
declare @SearchTerm nvarchar(4000) 
declare @ColumnName sysname

set @SearchTerm = N'2' -- Term to be searched for
set @ColumnName = N'customerID' --**column**

 set nocount on

 declare @TabCols table (
      id int not null primary key identity
      , table_schema sysname not null
      , table_name sysname not null
      , column_name sysname not null
      , data_type sysname not null
  )

insert into @TabCols (table_schema, table_name, column_name, data_type)
    select 
        t.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, c.DATA_TYPE
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
    join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c on t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                      and t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME
    where 1 = 1
      and t.TABLE_TYPE = 'base table'
      and c.DATA_TYPE not in ('image', 'sql_variant')
      and c.COLUMN_NAME like case when len(@ColumnName) > 0 then @ColumnName else '%' end
    order by c.TABLE_NAME, c.ORDINAL_POSITION

declare
  @table_schema sysname
, @table_name sysname
, @column_name sysname
, @data_type sysname
, @exists nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+
, @sql nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+
, @where nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+
, @run nvarchar(4000) -- Can be max for SQL2005+


while exists (select null from @TabCols) begin

select top 1
      @table_schema = table_schema
    , @table_name = table_name
   -- , @exists = 'select null from [' + table_schema + '].[' +    table_name + '] where 1 = 0'
    , @sql = 'delete''' + '[' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + ']' + ''' as TABLE_NAME, from [' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + '] where 1 = 0'
    , @where = ''
from @TabCols
order by id

while exists (select null from @TabCols where table_schema = @table_schema and table_name = @table_name) begin

    select top 1
          @column_name = column_name
        , @data_type = data_type
    from @TabCols
    where table_schema = @table_schema
        and table_name = @table_name
    order by id

    -- Special case for money
    if @data_type in ('money', 'smallmoney') begin
        if isnumeric(@SearchTerm) = 1 begin
            set @where = @where + ' or [' + @column_name + '] = cast(''' + @SearchTerm + ''' as ' + @data_type + ')' -- could also cast the column as varchar for wildcards
        end
    end
    -- Special case for xml
    else if @data_type = 'xml' begin
        set @where = @where + ' or cast([' + @column_name + '] as nvarchar(max)) like ''' + @SearchTerm + ''''
    end
    -- Special case for date
    else if @data_type in ('date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'smalldatetime', 'time') begin
        set @where = @where + ' or convert(nvarchar(50), [' + @column_name + '], 121) like ''' + @SearchTerm + ''''
    end
    -- Search all other types
    else begin
        set @where = @where + ' or [' + @column_name + '] like ''' + @SearchTerm + ''''
    end

    delete from @TabCols where table_schema = @table_schema and table_name = @table_name and column_name = @column_name

end

set @run = 'if exists(' + @exists + @where + ') begin ' + @sql + @where + ' print ''' + @table_name + ''' end'
print @run
exec sp_executesql @run

end

 set nocount off
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why won't it delete the values I set from all tables in the database?

Comment: You should be using sys.tables and sys.columns instead of the legacy INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views

Comment: Are you trying to update column values or delete the rows? You certainly don't need a loop here. And how can you not know what datatype you are looking for? Are you suggesting that CustomerID changes datatypes in every table?

Comment: Forget the code.  Your stated objective is not clear.  Are you looking delete records where there is a customerId field and it has a value of 2?  If you want to do something else, specify what it is as clearly as you can.

Comment: I am trying to delete rows

Comment: Yes @DanBracuk I am trying to delete records where there is a customer field and it has a value of 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another method based on the example posted by ewahner. The big difference is this doesn't use a cursor because you really don't need one for this.

```
declare @columnName nvarchar(255)
declare @intValue int
set @columnName = 'CustomerId'
set @intValue = 1
declare @DeleteValue varchar(10)
set @DeleteValue = convert(varchar(10), @intValue)

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql =  @sql + 'delete ' + object_name(c.object_id) + ' where ' + @columnName + ' = ' + @DeleteValue + ';'
from sys.columns c 
where c.name = @columnName

select @sql

/* Uncomment the line below in order to run */
--exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: when I use this code. It prints a message that the row is deleted but its not deleted in the tables

Comment: What do you mean it prints a message? Do you mean you see the delete statements but if you look in the table it is still there?

Comment: Do you see the part at the bottom? The comment that says UNCOMMENT THE LINE BELOW??? It is commented out until you are satisfied it will do what you want.

Comment: yep I did that and recieved and error that said. Could not find stored procedure.........

Comment: error message: "Could not find stored procedure 'delete customer where CustomerId = 2;delete Orders where CustomerId = 2;'."

Comment: Ahh...I didn't notice that ewahner had invalid syntax in the dynamic sql. When executing dynamic sql you either have to use exec(@sql) or better to use sp_executesql. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: One thing I would be careful of here is foreign keys. With the actual message you posted I would think it would crash if you have any RI in your system. You shouldn't be able to delete a Customer if they have Orders without first deleting the Orders. And of course you can't delete an Order without first deleting the OrderDetails. Unless of course you have cascading deletes on your foreign keys.

Comment: Yeah I had to actually add " ON DELETE CASCADE" because i ran into an error. BUT YOUR CODE WORKED PERFECTLY. THANKS

Comment: sorry...wasn't actually going to run this on my system ;-) and yeah I usually use sp_executesql but wasn't sure what version of SQL he was on.  The script above will only do this on one table...you still need the cursor to get all affected tables.

Comment: @ewahner how can you say this will only work on one table? Did you look at the code? It generates a delete statement dynamically for all tables it finds. Notice the semicolon in there to terminate each delete statement. You do NOT need a cursor for this type of thing.

Comment: Sorry didn't see the @sql +.  However if any of those deletes fail they all rollback.  Who knows if that is what is intended but that is the result.

Comment: Sure but this process is so sketchy in the first place does it really matter? :D

Answer (score 0):

Use at your own risk.  You will need to uncomment the exec line.  But first run it without uncommenting to make sure it gets the tables you want.

```
declare @columnName nvarchar(255)
declare @intValue int
set @columnName = 'CustomerId'
set @intValue = 1
declare curs cursor for 
    select object_name(c.object_id) as tableName
      from sys.columns c 
     where c.name = @columnName

declare @tableName nvarchar(255)
open curs
fetch next from curs into @tableName
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

    declare @sql nvarchar(1000)

    set @sql = 'delete ' + @tableName + ' where ' + @columnName + '=' + convert(varchar(10), @intValue)

    print @sql
    /* Uncomment the line below in order to run */
    --exec sp_executesql @sql
    fetch next from curs into @tableName
end
close curs
deallocate curs
```

Comment: it tells me it can not find stored procedure

Comment: There are no stored procedures.  This is just a script.  You can put a `use your_database_name` and a `go` and then execute this script.